# Ubuntu wont read DVD discs

Tags: dvd, drive

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My CD's are being read but my DVD's are not. I have a DVD with a bootable image and even that wont boot on startup. is it because of Ubuntu or is it a problem with my motherboard. My Pc is new and this never happened until I installed Ubuntu. Please guide me .

Comment: Does your reader read DVD's? Or is it just a CD reader? It would be better to write its Producer and Model directly here.

Comment: It does read and write DVD's because i burned the ubuntu iso with it. I am at office so i currently dont have the model number. But i am 100% sure it reads and writes DVD's.

Comment: Most likely a hardware issue with the DVD drive (see [here](http://superuser.com/a/888866/424824) for an explanation). Just to clarify, do you get this problem with all DVDs, or only video DVDs ? When you insert a DVD while Ubuntu is running, what happens ?

Comment: It happens to all DVD's... the drive just says empty. It used to work like 3 days ago... when i installed ubuntu.

Comment: If your PC does not boot from the DVD then something goes wrong **before** you get to Ubuntu. Test the DVD on another computer to make sure it is working. Check the motherboard firmware (EFI or BIOS) to make sure it detects the DVD and is still set as bootable.

Comment: Yeah.. Maybe the booting issue is with the bios but Ubuntu should show my data dvd's which have files in them right ? it doesn't do that also. And all those DVD's work on my Windows laptop.